# Flex app as DEBUG mode on PROD - disavantages?

Tags: apache-flex, debugging, production-environment

We have an internal flex app where performance is important.

Since it is internal, the test is barely done before the go life (well, that s the way it is), then we are used to debug on PROD. It is quite convenient debugging while you don't have to deploy the app again and again.

I know debug is forbidden on PROD for security reason, but it is fine in our context. Are there  another reason that we should disable it on PROD.

Note: I googled but only found "How to"!

Comment: File size will be bigger and execution will be slightly slower. That's about all I can think of. But I might be overlooking something.

Comment: Instead of releasing a debug version, I'd implement a proper logging mechanism. That way you won't have to deal with the performance hit of a debug version (however big or small it might be).

Comment: @RIAstar: you are right, the size is much bigger. 2-AI_Birdy: nice suggestion! My knowledge on Flex logging is limited though, will study more. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If performance is "important", using a debugger enabled compile is a bad idea unless (perhaps) your application is quite small. I've seen very noticeable differences in performance & initial download time.